# Typescript: How to express a generic function where the type is restricted to one of several types

Tags: templates, generics, typescript

For example if a method that adds two arguments, a and b, where they should be of the same type and that type should be either a string or a number.

Attempt 1:

```
function add(a: string | number, b: string | number) { 
    return a + b; 
}
```

This won't work because the types of a and b may not match; so the resulting error makes sense: `error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and 'string | number'.`

Attempt 2:

```
function add<T extends string | number>(a: T, b: T) {
    return a + b;
}
```

This returns the same error code: `error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'.`

Attempt 3:

```
function add(a: string, b: string): string;
function add(a: number, b: number): number;
function add(a: any, b: any) {
    return a + b;
}
```

This (function overloading) works properly, but seems like overkill. Is there a more elegant way to express this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also combine your attempts 2 & 3 like this:

```
function add<T extends string | number>(a: T, b: T): T;
function add(a: any, b: any) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
// Return type is `number`
add(1, 2);
// Return type is `string`
add('1', '2');
add<number>(1, 2);
add<string>('1', '2');
```

... and these cause type errors as expected:

```
add(1, '2');
add<number>('1', '2');
add<string>(1, 2);
add(true, false);
```

However, if you're not going to use the input type, then I would stick with just function overloads. Easiest to understand in my opinion.

Comment: Interesting. Do you happen to know why that works and 2) doesn't? I've always thought of overloading as merely a way to add multiple signatures; there is clearly some other magic going on.

Comment: #2 won’t work because the `string|number` union type is used in the implementation signature. This causes the function’s implementation to be checked as `<string|number> + <string|number>`. When a function is overloaded, the call signature(s) and implementation signature are separate. When the function above is called, the `string|number` union type is checked, but the function’s implementation will be typed checked as `<any> + <any>`. TS can use type inference to figure out the return type in the call signature(s), but it can’t in the case of `<string|number> + <string|number>`.