# TypeScript, bind multiple params to same type

Tags: typescript, generics

Is there a way to achieve the following with TypeScript?

```
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

I want the following to compile:

```
add(1, 2);
add("hello ", "world");
```

But I do not want the following to compile:

```
add(4, "world");
add("hello ", 4);
```

Note also, I want it to compile for strings and numbers only.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357839/typescript-how-to-express-a-generic-function-where-the-type-is-restricted-to-on

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with generic types:

```
function add<T extends string | number>(x: T, y: T): T {
  return x + y;
}

add<string>("a", "b"); // OK
add<number>(5, 3); // OK
add<boolean>(true, false); // Type 'boolean' does not satisfy constraint 'string | number'
```

Notice that you don't always need to give the generic type when calling the function, as long as it satisfies the constraints:

```
add("a", "b"); // OK
add(5, 3); // OK
add(5, "b"); // Type argument candidate 'number' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'string'.
add(true, "c"); // Type argument candidate 'boolean' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'string'.
```

As you can see, this is saying:

- `x` and `y` must be the same type
- that type must either be a `string` or a `number` (or an extension of either)

The TypeScript compiler is clever enough to work out the type without specifying the generics in the calls (but you must put them in the definition).

---

As you noticed, this is an issue with the TypeScript compiler. I've [logged it on the TypeScript Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12410) repo.

For now, you can do this:

```
function add<T extends string | number>(x: T, y: T): T {
    return <any>x + <any>y;
}
```

`x` and `y` are still of type `T` (ensured by the compiler) but we trick it into letting us do `+` on them.

Comment: Sadly it does not compile...

`Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'`

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? It may be an issue with the compiler.

Comment: @JamesMonger Nope, it doesn't work even in typescript 2.2 (@next).

Comment: It's an issue with the compiler @Erigotto, I've logged it on the TypeScript GitHub. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12410

Comment: I've updated my answer for a workaround until it is fixed @Erigotto.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

```
function add<T extends string | number>(x: T, y: T): T;
function add(x: any, y: any) {
  return x + y;
}

let s = add("a", "b"); // fine
let n = add(1, 2); // fine
let n2 = add(1,"2"); // error
```

This is how you have to do it for now, although I'm glad @JamesMongar opened GitHub issue. If T extends the primitives string or number, then + operator on T must definitely be legit.

Comment: Nice solution @Erigotto